# Fails to pass argument to a Function using scanf()

Tags: c

I can't pass an argument to a function using `scanf()`.

```
//ADD Function
void add(int x, int y){
    int result = x + y;
    printf("%d + %d = %d\n", x, y, result);
}


int main(void)
{
    printf("Enter The First Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("Enter The Second Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &y);

    add(x, y);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting `Undeclared` Error.

Is there a way to fix that? Is it even possible?

Comment: scanf needs the address of the argument to change the value:

Comment: scanf("%d",&x);

Comment: also you need to declare and define x and y

Comment: Oh sorry the address thing wasn't the case. I just forgot to put it in stackoverflow code. And I already declared them on add() Function. Do i need to create a global variable?

Comment: I am surprised this compiles the way it is.  Even defined in the function they are not visible to main?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use variable x and y in scanf without declaring it.So you have to first declare it before using it in scanf.

```
#include<stdio.h>

//ADD Function
void add(int x, int y){
int result = x + y;
printf("%d + %d = %d\n", x, y, result);
}


int main(void)
{
    int x;
    int y;
    printf("Enter The First Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("Enter The Second Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &y);

    add(x, y);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And also initialize x,y with zero.

Answer (score 0):

You need `int x, y;` in `main()` so that there are locally scoped (look this up!) variables allocated on the stack, to pass pointers to `scanf()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  You can write the code that way, and the program will work.
You must declare the variables X Y so that it knows where to input
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //ADD Function
    void add(){
            int x,y;
          printf("Enter The First Number: ");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        printf("Enter The Second Number: ");
        scanf("%d", &y);
        int result = x + y;
        printf("%d + %d = %d\n", x, y, result);
    }


    int main(void)
    {

        add();

        return 0;
    }
```